# Find speed of an aircraft flying towards an observer

Tags: calculus, derivatives

An aircraft is flying towards an observer at an altitude of $2000$ m. When the angle of observation, $z$, (between the ground and the aircraft) is 30 degrees, the rate of change of this angle is $2$ degrees per second. Let $x$ = the horizontal distance.

Estimate the speed of the aircraft to the nearest $10$ km/h.

Very lost as to what to do here, I have spent the last hour trying but no progress. I get $x = \tfrac{2}{\tan(z)}$, I differentiate with the quotient rule, to get $\frac{dx}{dz}$, which I then multiply by $\frac{dz}{dt} = 2$ to find $\frac{dx}{dt}$. $\frac{dx}{dz}$ for $z=30$ comes out as $-8$. $-8 \times 2$ is $-16$. But obviously, the plane is not moving at $16$ km/s.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Maybe get rid of degrees, they don't work well if derivatives of trig functions are involved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a conversion from angle in degrees to angle in radians.

$\dfrac{dx}{dt} = \dfrac{dx}{dz_{rad}}*\dfrac{dz_{rad}}{dz_{deg}}*\dfrac{dz_{deg}}{dt}$

Where $z_{rad} = z_{deg} * \dfrac{2 \pi}{360}$

Comment: Is this actually necessary? I thought that as long as my calculator was in degrees mode then this shouldn't matter?

Comment: I'm not sure how clever your calculator is, but the units of the equation have to balance: $\dfrac{km}{sec} = \dfrac{km}{rad}*\dfrac{rads}{deg}*\dfrac{degs}{sec}$

Comment: Using radians gave the correct answer, though I'm still not sure what you mean. I thought all of my units were in degrees? Or are trig derivatives always meant to be in radians?

Comment: @DylanCleaver Yes, trig derivatives require radian mode.